# using Django to query a MySQL database using the same connection as the ORM database

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, orm

I have a MySQL server providing access to both a database for the Django ORM and a separate database called "STATES" that I built. I would like to query tables in my STATES database and return results (typically a couple of rows) to Django for rendering, but I don't know the best way to do this.

One way would be to use Django directly. Maybe I could move the relevant tables into the Django ORM database? I'm nervous about doing this because the STATES database contains large tables (10 million rows x 100 columns), and I worry about deleting that data or messing it up in some other way (I'm not very experienced with Django). I also imagine I should avoid creating a separate connection for each query, so I should use the Django connection to query STATE tables?

Alternatively, I could treat the STATE database as existing on a totally different server. I could import SQLAlchemy, create a connection, query STATE.table, return the result, and close that connection.

Which is better, or is there another path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/) describe how to connect to multiple databases by adding another database ("state_db") to DATABASES in settings.py, I can then do the following.

```
from django.db import connections
def query(lname)
    c = connections['state_db'].cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT last_name FROM STATE.table WHERE last_name=%s;",[lname])
    rows = c.fetchall()
    ...
```

This is slower than I expected, but I'm guessing this is close to optimal because it uses the open connection and Django without adding extra complexity.